# PySpark Row-wise Function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am brand new to spark (pyspark) and am unsure why the following works fine:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType,DoubleType

print (sq_lmi.printSchema())

def calc_V1(row):
    a=row.SQFT_ID

    V1=a
    return V1




calc_V1_udf = udf(calc_V1, DoubleType())  #register the function and its return type

new_df = sq_lmi.withColumn("V1", calc_V1_udf(struct([sq_lmi[x] for x in sq_lmi.columns]))) #apply - the struct is needed to send the entire row
new_df.select('V1').show(5)
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- LMI_HMT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SQFT: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- SQFT_ID: double (nullable = true)

None
+-------------------+
|                 V1|
+-------------------+
| 29.335526315789473|
| 20.689655172413794|
|  22.97872340425532|
| 23.776223776223777|
|0.18512170037709977|
+-------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

But, If I do anything to the row before returning it (adding 5.0, multiplying 5.0 or adding / multiplying another column of 'row') an error occurs.:

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct
    from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType,DoubleType

    print (sq_lmi.printSchema())

    def calc_V1(row):
        a=row.SQFT_ID*5.0

        V1=a
        return V1




    calc_V1_udf = udf(calc_V1, DoubleType())  #register the function and its return type

    new_df = sq_lmi.withColumn("V1", calc_V1_udf(struct([sq_lmi[x] for x in sq_lmi.columns]))) #apply - the struct is needed to send the entire row
    new_df.select('V1').show(5)



root
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- LMI_HMT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SQFT: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- SQFT_ID: double (nullable = true)

None

Py4JJavaErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-d6c37eed3db5> in <module>()
     16 
     17 new_df = sq_lmi.withColumn("V1", calc_V1_udf(struct([sq_lmi[x] for x in sq_lmi.columns]))) #apply - the struct is needed to send the entire row
---> 18 new_df.select('V1').show(5)

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate)
    285         +---+-----+
    286         """
--> 287         print(self._jdf.showString(n, truncate))
    288 
    289     def __repr__(self):

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1884.showString.
```

Comment: Your code works just fine in my notebook. Did You try to restart kernel?

Comment: It does not. How did you recreate the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probable is that you have Null values and You are not checking for them.

Try doing something like:

```
def calc_V1(row):
    if row is not None and row.SQFT_ID is not None :
        a=row.SQFT_ID*5.0

        V1=a
        return V1
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: That did it! So a null or nan will cause the execution to cease, not simply return a null for the value of that row?

Comment: You were performing operations on a Null value, which caused an exception. I prefer to perform such simple operations using `.withColumn()` not an udf. Also udf's are kind of slow, as they require context switch.

Comment: I tried using this: new_df2=sq_lmi.withColumn("V1", sq_lmi.SQFT_ID*sq_lmi.SQFT )

and it worked and did not blow up with the 1 null record.

Comment: yes, `withColumn()` will handle this for You. However,  sometimes creating UDF is the only option and then You need to check for Nulls Yourself or filter them out before udf.